is the field name required to be called `id` for caching and graphql object identification in graphql
Is the field name required to be called id for caching and graphql object identification in graphql?
It is very confusing from GraphQL Documentation which uses id as field name in all of their examples.
https://graphql.org/learn/global-object-identification/
https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types

afaik, it just needs to be of the ID! type.
